# instagram sniffer. Как узнать какие get/post запросы отправляются при разных действиях?

Tags: post, get, instagram

Каким образом можно узнать какие GET/POST запросы нужно выполнить для получения определённых данных в instagram.
Например для того чтобы получить список подписчиков нужно отправить обычный http запрос на url https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/ с параметрами query_hash="37479f2b8209594dde7facb0d904896a" и variables="{"id": "(account.id)","first": 50}". Об этом я узнал отсюда [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658723/how-to-get-followers-and-following-list-in-instagram-via-http-requests).
И меня как раз интересует как люди это поняли.
Я попробовал использовать tcpdump, но это не помогло мне.

Comment: [instagram api](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) и [API Graph для Instagram](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/)

Comment: мб это просто [из запросов достали](https://www.diggernaut.com/blog/how-to-scrape-pages-infinite-scroll-extracting-data-from-instagram/)

Comment: Наверное это вопрос типа "Как стать хакером?". Поставить монитор запросов (WireShark например), делать действия и мониторить запросы. Читать о сетевых взаимодейсвиях, об авторизированых и неавторизированых запросов. Возможно перечитать моного хакерских статей. Кроме знаний ещё нужно понимание что с чем стыкуется, и немного опыта в этой сфере. tcpdump - слабый.